# How to save login Information locally in android

Tags: android

I have made an android app which working fine. I implemented the Login functionality in it. Can anyone guide me how to store the login credentials of the user so that the user does not have to login everytime he/she starts the app and when user logout then clear the stored login information.

Actually i want that user does not have to enter login information everytime when he/she starts the app.How can i do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Store value use sharepreference. i am pasting code here..use it.

**Create Share Preference:**

```
SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor Ed=sp.edit();
Ed.putString("Unm",Value );              
Ed.putString("Psw",Value);   
Ed.commit();
```

**Get Value from Share preference:**

```
SharedPreferences sp1=this.getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);

String unm=sp1.getString("Unm", null);       
String pass = sp1.getString("Psw", null);
```

When user logout then you can set null value into sharedpreference.

Comment: Actually i want that user does not have to enter login information everytime when he/she starts the app.i used code as u type here but i did not got solved my problem............

Comment: ok, so you can set one boolean in share preference if islogin is true then it move next screen.

Comment: use `MODE_PRIVATE` instead of magic `0` when calling `getSharedPreferences`.

Comment: MODE_PRIVATE won't make your preferences any safe. Saving this without any encryption will be a serious vulnerability. There are many things to do this right, but the android sdk has `EncryptedSharedPreferences` which is still better than the ordinary one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is Shared Preference. It is useless to create a whole Database and query it, for just one entry.
And File System doesnt provide a structured solution. (key value pairs)

For UI, I think that you should have two Fragments
if the user is registered show him The `MainFragment`
and if not the `LoginFragment`

Comment: Don't forget to protect the data you save there.

Answer (score 0):

Create external database file with credential table in this table create appropriate columns like username,password etc..here if you have registered users then store those users details in credential table.Finally copy that database in assests folder then using SqliteOpenHelper class copy that external database to phone memory.Here you need to maintain registration page with conditions.If the user completes the registrations procedure with your conditions then store his/her details in credential table.When user wants to login to the App please check the username and password in credential table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use each one of the following methods:
- SharedPreferences
- Database
- File system

Of course, each method has it pros and cons.