# How to keep android applications always be logged in state in xamarin MVVmCross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

i want to do exact same implematation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771061/how-to-save-login-information-locally-in-android) but i am in Xamarin MvvmCross.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use: https://github.com/has-taiar/KeyChain.Net

It uses native implementation of each platform, so you don't need to think about where to store login information, it will always be present in most secure place on each platform.

The syntax is easy and straightforward:

iOS Example

```
var helper = new KeyChain.Net.XamarinIOS.KeyChainHelper();
var isSaved = helper.SetKey("myKey", "myKeyValue");
var keyValue = helper.GetKey("myKey");
var isDeleted = helper.DeleteKey("myKey");
```

Android Example:

```
var helper = new KeyChain.Net.XamarinAndroid.KeyChainHelper(myActivity, "myKeyProtectionPassword");
var isSaved = helper.SetKey("myKey", "myKeyValue");
var keyValue = helper.GetKey("myKey");
var isDeleted = helper.DeleteKey("myKey");
```

WP Example:

```
var helper = new KeyChain.Net.XamarinWinRT.KeyChainHelper();
var isSaved = helper.SetKey("myKey", "myKeyValue");
var keyValue = helper.GetKey("myKey");
var isDeleted = helper.DeleteKey("myKey");
```

Comment: What about using SharedPreferences ? What is the best way?

Comment: SharedPreferences available only on Android. If you are developing only for Android, then fine, use them. KeyCahin.net is just a wrapper that provides you with unified syntax calls for each platform. Under the hood, it still SharedPreferences for Android, KeyChainManager for iOS and etc.